# Vmware Server can be exported b/w OS

Tags: vmware-server

I have several virtual machines in Vmware server.
Can i export vmware server to new Host OS (both same but diff computer) so that all machines gets imported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to export your VMs as appliances, which can then be imported on your other server.

Comment: You mean to say that full server can't be exported but only virtual machines. I think that will be a lengthy process